# How to add a spring-boot jar as a dependency in a new spring-boot project without changing the original pom

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml

In order to add azure app insights in an old spring-boot jar(which already has micrometer), I've created a new spring-boot project and added it as a dependency. However, after a successful Maven build, while executing it as spring-boot app, I'm getting `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class]` exception. Here are my two POM files,

POM of the old spring-boot jar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <parent>
    <artifactId>microservice</artifactId>
    <groupId>my-app-service</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>microservice-my-app</artifactId>

  <dependencies>

    <!-- few dependencies -->

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>app</classifier>
              <mainClass>com.my.package.MyApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

POM of the new spring-boot project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.my.app.appinsights</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservice-my-app-appinsights</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>microservice-my-app-appinsights</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <applicationinsights.version>1.1.1</applicationinsights.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <applicationinsights.version>2.5.1</applicationinsights.version>
    </properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>my-app-service</groupId>
            <artifactId>microservice-my-app</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${applicationinsights.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-spring-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
              <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Implementation-Version>1.0.0</Implementation-Version>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>       
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>    
                        <configuration> 
                            <classifier>app</classifier>
                            <mainClass>com.my.app.appinsights.MicroserviceMyAppinsightsApplication</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Exception stack:

```
2020-02-03 13:48:39.726  WARN 2420 --- [           main] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.microsoft.applicationinsights.autoconfigure.ApplicationInsightsWebMvcAutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2020-02-03 13:48:39.734  INFO 2420 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-02-03 13:48:39.742 ERROR 2420 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.microsoft.applicationinsights.autoconfigure.ApplicationInsightsWebMvcAutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:596)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:302)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:586)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$900(ConfigurationClassParser.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:805)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:801)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:771)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
    at com.my.app.appinsights.MicroserviceMyAppinsightsApplication.main(MicroserviceMyAppinsightsApplication.java:14)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:51)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:682)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:995)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:332)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:586)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

It turns out that the azure app-insights needs `spring-boot-starter-web` to work properly. But since that jar is already present in the parent of the existing jar, I can not add it to my current POM file. This might mean I might not be importing the old jar in my new POM correctly.

How do I add the existing spring-boot jar as a dependency in my new spring-boot's POM file, without making any modifications in the existing jar or its POM?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the packing of both the projects, if the child project has different packing then parent project, then you need to add component scan at your child main class from where you are running your project.

For example,

```
Parent project has package name 

com.my.app
```

And

```
child project had package name 
com.my.app.appinsights
```

then you need to add component scan in main class

```
@ComponentScan("com.my.app")
```

Spring boot by default scan beans from sub-packages of the main class. To override the component scan you need to add this annotation so that it will scan beans from given package also.

Comment: Yeah I've already done that...

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
"com"})

Comment: Can you change it to this
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(
"com")